# Как записать двумерный вектор в двоичный файл?

Tags: c++, vector, binary

Предположим, что у меня имеется какой-то двумерный вектор:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> main_vector;
std::vector<int> temp_vector;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) temp_vector.push_back(i);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) main_vector.push_back(temp_vector);
```

Как записать его в двоичный файл? Соответственно, размерность неизвестна.
Знаю, что стандартным образом как с массивами не прокатит.

```
bin_file.open("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
bin_file.write((char *)&main_vector, sizeof(main_vector)); //не сработает
```

Comment: у вектора, вообщето есть свой метод `size()`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch сходу набросал. как создать вектор - не важно. Я это не компилировал даже, сам вопрос в том, как его записать в файл, а как создать уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение вот (проверено):

```
  std::ofstream bin_file;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> main_vector;
  main_vector.resize(5);

  const int n = 5;
  const int m = 5;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; n < 5; i++) {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; m < 5; j++) {
      main_vector[i].push_back(j);
    }
  }
//демонстрация в поток вывода элементов нашего вектора
  for (int i {}; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j {}; j < m; ++j) {
      std::cout << main_vector[i][j] << ' ';
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
//запись в файл (расширение УКАЗАННО ВОПРОШАЮЩИМ!)
  bin_file.open("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  for (int i{}; i < main_vector.size(); ++i) {
    bin_file.write((char *)&main_vector[i][0],
                   main_vector[i].size() * sizeof(main_vector[i][0]));
  }
  bin_file.close();
```

Ну а проверить что у вас вывелось в файл можно следующим образом:

```
  char array[n * m * sizeof(main_vector[0][0])];

  read_file.open("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  read_file.read(array, sizeof(array));
  read_file.close();

  int *arr = reinterpret_cast<int *>(array);
  for (int i {}; i < n * m; ++i) {
    std::cout << *arr << ' ';
    ++arr;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хреновое решение. Просто кишка из элементов, никакой структуры... С чего вы решили, что читать назад нужно в массив, а не в вектор векторов, во-вторых, с чего вы решили, что читать надо ровно 25 чисел? Откуда это известно (у автора четко указано - **Соответственно размерность не известна**)? Про мелочь - давать расширение `.txt` бинарному файлу - не упоминаю :) Это - пояснение, почему я поставил ответу минус...

Comment: @Harry ну вы говорите буд-то это не пример как нужно делать, а работа, которую нужно сдавать))) Во-первых, по поводу куда считывать - да ничего я не рашал куда считывать (об этом даже вопроса не было!), просто это выводит на консоль то, что у нас записалось в файл в ЧИТАЕМОМ формате. Тобишь это просто проверка того, что запись сработала верно. Во-вторых, по поводу 25 чисел - это вытекает из первого, надеюсь почему пояснять не надо. Третье - то же самое. Что касается расширения - ну это вы не по адресу, об этом вам лучше спросить автора вопроса.

Comment: @Harry надеюсь я все объяснил?

Comment: Вы могли не давать компилируемый текст, но дать понимание, как делать. Вы дали ответ верный по форме, а по сути - совершенно некорректный.

Comment: @Harry ну вам не угодишь))) Для начала посмотрите на вопрошающего, у которого репутация на данный момент равняется `13` и ответьте мне какая форма ответа ему будет более информативная? Именно для информативности и нужна нижняя часть, где я считываю данные из файла и вывожу на консоль. Но ладно, ради вас я отредактирую ответ так, чтобы вас он устроил)

Comment: @Harry так лучше?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch то есть судя по нижней части примера мы считаем обратно в одномерный массив?

Comment: @ВладиславВернер да, НО! Это не часть решения, что и указано в ответе, просто демонстрация того, что ввод в файл был корректный (так как в файле нечеловеко-читаемые символы)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, я понимаю и уже проверил ваш способ, действительно всё записалось. Дело в том, что мне нужно ещё и обратно считать в двумерный вектор, но там уже сам додумаю скорее всего

Comment: Добавьте вывод размерностей векторов. При считывании (даже для проверки) читаете первой число из файла, создаете main_vector нужного размера. Затем в цикле читаете размер его элемента, создаете вектор, считываете его данные, помещаете этот вектор в main_vector. Как-то так (и исправьте в соответствии с этим ваш ответ, который ТС по неопытности принял, посчитав ...)

Comment: @avp у меня в файл пишется список структур из нескольких полей, одно из которых вектор векторов, поэтому размерность векторов - сомнительное решение для каждого элемента списка если делать

Comment: @avp СЧИТЫВАНИЕ - НЕ ЧАСТЬ ОТВЕТА!!! Вы читать не умеете что ли? Вы видите что в вопросе хоть что-то сказано о чтении из файла? Пример чтения - это просто ДЕМОНСТРАЦИЯ, ЧТО ВСЕ ЗАПИСАЛОСЬ ВЕРНО! Можно удалить к чертям нижнюю часть и ответ все равно будет верным, так как он выше.

Comment: @ВладиславВернер, и что дальше вы с этими данными (не зная размеров) собираетесь делать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, читать я умею. А еще я умею заглядывать на пару шагов вперед

Comment: @avp ни мне, ни вам не известно, что и как собирается делать с этими данными вопрошающий. Я это говорю просто на том основании, что знаю, что экстрасенсов не существует! Я дал ответ ровно на то, что спрашивал вопрошающий, с демонстрацией того, что все вывелось верно. Я отвечал НЕ ВАМ!!! Если хотите ответ, подходящий под ваши критерии - пожалуйста, задавайте вопрос, только не забудьте в нем прописать чего вы хотите! Еще раз: я дал ответ ровно на то, что спрашивали. Что собирается с этим делать вопрошающий - мне неизвестно, соответственно я не могу ему ответить на то, что он не спрашивал.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а считать обратно из файла получится как-то в тот же одномерный массив как у вас, не зная про размерность?

Comment: @ВладиславВернер да, можно, для этого нужно использовать `string` - в нее считываете файл до конца, потом с помощью метода `c_str` приводите к виду `char *` а дальше как в демонстрации

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, то что вы (надеюсь, пока) не можете предвидеть подобные повороты я не сомневаюсь.

Comment: @avp я счас посмотрел правила форума и что-то там ничего не сказано про "предвидение" - думаю вы ошиблись, это не битва экстрасенсов, вам на другой сайт.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch эх, а у меня список структур там с полями)

Comment: @ВладиславВернер не понял, где, в векторе?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вектор векторов - одно из полей структуры. Список структур пишется в бинарник

Comment: @ВладиславВернер не понимаю что вы хотите

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да у меня просто ситуация немного сложнее и я если честно не ожидал, что это будет так трудоёмко с моей реализацией. В общем я пишу программу, где пользователь может залогиниться (логин и пароль - поля структуры), и сыграть в игру (количество ходов, количество побед и общее количество сыгранных игр - пишется в массив из трёх элементов (тоже поля структуры)). А сами ходы на поле у меня записываются в вектор векторов. Там координаты каждой ячейки. Ход №1 - это 1 1, ход №2 - это 2 3 к примеру. Пытаюсь реализовать сохранение игры таким образом.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch звучит, конечно, костыльно, но всё удалось записывать правильно до вектора векторов и я уже просто стою на пути того, чтобы отказаться от этой идеи сохранения игры)

Comment: @ВладиславВернер детали реализации игры совершенно излишни - что у вы хотите записывать и что у вас не получается?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вот у меня есть метод класса, где по полям в файл пишутся данные (логин, пароль, статистика), они пишутся и считываются правильно. Теперь стоит задача записать вектор векторов и считать его обратно потом. Как записать вы мне показали, если мы не знаем размерность, всё вышло. Проблема теперь считать обратно его в какую-то структуру, чтобы потом перенести обратно в вектор векторов, не зная размерность внешнего вектора так сказать. Вложенный вектор всегда из двух элементов (2 координаты)

Comment: @ВладиславВернер сдесь зависит от реализации вашего вектора векторов. Как я понял, ваш вектор состоит из двух векторов, так? Если размеры у этих векторов всегда одинаковы, то все просто: считываете из файла данные, выясняете сколько элементов (это будет четное число) и создаете два вектора каждый размером в половину от количества элементов. Если же вектора разной длинны, то тут уже посложнее: нужно либо записывать их размер, либо при записи устанавливать некий разделитель (что является плохой идеей).

Comment: @ВладиславВернер, просто прочтите мой комментарий выше -- `Добавьте вывод размерностей векторов. При считывании...`

Answer (score 1):

Для большей обобщенности будем считать, что вектора внутри вектора могут иметь разный размер.

Тогда примерно (не компилирую - просто набросок!)

```
// Пишем размер внешнего вектора
size_t sz = main_vector.size();
stream.write(&sz,sizeof(sz));

for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
{
    // То же самое для каждого внутреннего:
    vector<int>& v = main_vector[i];
    size_t sz = v.size();
    stream.write(&sz,sizeof(sz));
    // Пишем данные
    for(size_t j = 0; j < sz; ++j)
    {
        int n = v[j];
        stream.write(&n,sizeof(n));
    }
    // Или, поскольку в векторе данные лежат подряд -
    // просто stream.write(v.data(), sizeof(int)*sz);
}
```

Читать - в обратном порядке. Сначала - общее количество векторов внутри основного, потом по ним цикл - с чтением количества int'ов и чтением со вставкой соответствующего количества значений (или, опять же, создание вектора с известным количеством элементов и чтение прямо во внутренний буфер...)

Comment: я не понел для чего нужно записать в файл размер вектора?

Comment: Harry, а так?...     for (size_t i = 0; i < main_vector.size(); ++i)
        bin_file.write((char *)&main_vector[i],
                       (sizeof(main_vector[i].value_type)) * main_vector[i].size());

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Первый вопрос - потому что никто не гарантирует, что у вас в файле только вектор, и только один. Второе - нет, плохо, потому что в примере автора `main_vector[i].value_type` - вектор, а не POD, так что будет неверная запись.

Comment: main_vector[i]  это  вектор, а   main_vector[i].value_type  это тип элемента этого вектора

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::vector<char16_t>> main_vector;
std::vector<char16_t> temp_vector;

temp_vector.push_back( u'H' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'E' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'L' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'L' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'O' );

main_vector.push_back( temp_vector );

temp_vector.clear();

temp_vector.push_back( u'W' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'O' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'R' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'L' );
temp_vector.push_back( u'D' );

main_vector.push_back( temp_vector );

std::ofstream out( "out.bin", std::ios::binary );

for( auto i : main_vector ){
    out.write( (char*)i.data(), i.size() * sizeof(char16_t) );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А читать как будете? Откуда видно, что это 2 вектора по 5 символов, а не 5 векторов по два? Или три по три, и какие-то следующие данные?

Comment: @Harry это и дураку понятно что где-то нужно хранить подобную информацию. Я всего лишь показал альтернативный вариант записи, в соответствии с вопросом. Не запрещено.